# Unsolvable SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need help with a MySQL-Query.

```
Table Company:
(PK) ID_Company
CompanyName
...

Table Address:
(PK) ID_Address
(FK) ID_Company
Street
...

Table ContactPerson:
(PK) ID_ContactPerson
(PK) ID_Company
PersonName
...
```

Now I want so create a SELECT statement to get a list with all customers. This should look like that:

```
ID_Company    CompanyName    Street    PersonName
    1           Google        Test        Joe
```

But a company can have none, one or multiple addresses and contact persons. I only want to select one address and one contact person in this query. And this is the point where I don't know how to do that.

One thing I tried is to select the MIN of ID_Address, but that doesn't work if a company doesn't have a address and and a contact person.

I hope you understand what I am trying to do.

Thank you all for your help! :)

Comment: How to chose address or contact person if a company has several of those?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is not really a SQL problem; it's a data-architecture problem. We can easily tell you how to get *an* address and *a* contact person per company, but only you can decide *which* address or contact person you want. If you don't care which address or contact person you get, then you should update your question to say that.

Comment: Start with LEFT JOINs.

Comment: That is the point: It doesn't matter in real which address is selected. Perfect would be the one which was created first (PKs have auto_increment, so in this case the address/person with the lowest PK)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join` and aggregation:

```
select c.ID_Company, c.company_name, min(street), min(person_name)
from company c left join
     address a
     on c.ID_Company = a.ID_Company left join
     ContactPerson cp
     on cp.ID_Company = a.ID_Company
group by c.ID_Company, c.company_name;
```

Comment: At first, thank you for your answer.

But if I SELECT a.ID_Company, what if there is no Address for this company? The PK for this row at ID_Company will be null.

Comment: I modified this query and got it to work. Way simpler than I thought! Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: @arahman . . . I format my code *exactly* the way I want it formatted.  `LEFT JOIN` is an operator that connects two tables.  I do not start lines with binary operators.  The left-justified keywords all start SQL clauses.